# Mockito RestTemplate ResponseEntity giving null pointer exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I am new to Mockito and facing a null pointer exception with RestTemplate. Can someone please help and let me know what is wrong with my mock service.

Service:

```
public List<String> getval(String id) {
    String path = "/abc" + id;
    ResponseEntity<tnclass> RE = restTemplate.getForEntity(id, tnClass.class);
    if (RE != null && RE.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
        return RE.getBody().gettnNumbers();
    }else{
        return Collections.<String>emptyList();
    }
}
```

MockService:

```
private RestTemplate res = mock(RestTemplate.class);

public List<String> getval(String id) {
    ResponseEntity<tnClass> my = mock(ResponseEntity.class);
    tnClass tn = mock(tnClass.class);
    List<String> l = new ArrayList();
    l.add(0, "t1");
    l.add(1, "t2");
    tn.setId(id);
    tn.settnNumbers(l);
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForEntity(path, tnClass.class, tn)).thenReturn(my);
    List<String> finallist = my.getBody().gettnNumbers();
    return finallist;
}
```

Comment: the `when` uses a `getForEntity` with 3 args but the tested code uses a 2 args signature

Comment: Yourr MockService is missing some code, `path` variable is not defined, no return statement... Also it doesn't look like a test, what are you using this for?

Comment: there are no path variables, return is there where i am returning ResponseEntity. I am trying to create a mock service and then calling it from my junit test

Comment: path variable are not there, added the return code, but my issue is ResponseEntity is throwing null, why is that? I am trying to create a mock service which i am calling in my junit test

Comment: it has three arguments only. Its not working

Comment: First of all, you should clarify what you are trying to test? The service itself or some other entity calling the service? Ideally you should provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) that reproduces your problem.